# How can MVC5 and Web API 2 share the same login/authentication token

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an application using MVC 5. Parts of the application use Web API 2 i.e. some pages do considerable work using AJAX. 
Authorization is fairly complex as it involve row level security for may tables in the database.

I have no problem implementing MVC 5 security and neither have problem implanting Web API 2 security using Basic Authentication and SSL
Trouble is that once the user has logged in and page is loaded then subsequent calls are made through AJAX to Web API 2. How can I use the existing credentials from JavaScript to make calls to web api